# 3amp fuse blows only when set to heat

Tags: circuit-breaker, relay

The 3amp fuse blows when set to heat. I replaced it and it doesn't blow when set to cool. I'm not an electrician but looked on the web and have changed the transformer a capacitor and a contactor on the inside furnace and one contactor on the outside ac unit. The outside unit is 4yrs old and inside is 8yrs old. Need some help. Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both your thermostat and your furnace, as well as the wiring diagram of the furnace please?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to upload pics, I'm new to this

Comment: Try hitting "edit" in the "share edit ..." at the bottom-left of your post, then the "mountain and sun" button in the text editor's toolbar

Comment: Says my photos at too big to upload

Comment: Then post them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post links to them here

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4SOUkXQ see if this works

Comment: This started when we had a power brown out early last year

Comment: Wow, what kind of system? Gas? Electric? Heat pump? Is the fuse on the thermostat, furnace control board. Way two many possibilities at this point. We could guess there is an outside compressor , if a heat pump a reversing valve has to switch that could be a guess but with the information provided that is jumping to 1 conclusion and is bad as changing capacitors and transformers without understanding what it is first.

Comment: It's a separate electric furnace inside my mobile home, we used it before we hade the outside ac unit hooked up when we bought the house 4yrs ago 3.5 ton unit, not a heat pump

Comment: Ok that takes out a reversing valve, is the fuse that is blowing the one on the PC board the one on the 24v supply line? You changed out a contactor was it the main one for heat or the one for the fan?  When you replaced the fuse was it a fast blow single fine wire, or a slow blow usually a coil of wire around a core? You haven’t updated to a new thermostat have you?

Comment: The contactor is on the bottom left of the pic and the fuse is a fast blow. It does not have a board in it. One of the word from the transformer runs to the fuse and I can't remember where the other wire runs. Like I said, the ac runs fine but blows as soon as you set to heat. There is a relay they call an inducer fan relay in the top left of the pic. They say it could be bad as well. I have a multi meter but can't find it